# Unknown compilation error

Tags: tables

I have a really strange compilation error in LaTeX. What is wrong with this piece of code which LaTeX sees but won't say. I really would like to say more about this problem, but it is really mysterious.

```
\documentclass[•]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Arkusz2'
%\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrr}
%\begin{tabular}{rr}
%\toprule
%f & r
%\end{tabular}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Arkusz2'
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrr}

        DG &            &                       DGALG &            &                        DJ &            &                           BR &            \\

     12.0  &        3.92  &         27.5  &         4.9  &      14.0  &     21.56  &        24.5  &     12.74  \\

     38.5  &        6.86  &         48.5  &         8.82  &         43.0  &     13.72  &        61.5  &     12.74  \\

     54.5  &        26.46  &        69.5  &         8.82  &         24.5  &     10.78  &        66.5  &         6.86  \\

     60.0  &        1.96  &         85.5  &         14.7  &         30.0  &     11.76  &        75.5  &         8.82  \\

     74.5  &        6.86  &         87.0  &         7.84  &         44.5  &     36.26  &        87.0  &         5.88  \\

     94.5  &        4.9  &      103.5  &        18.62  &        24.0  &         19.6  &         90.0  &     15.68  \\

     96.5  &        24.5  &     108.5  &        6.86  &         57.5  &         34.3  &         72.0  &         5.88  \\

     94.5  &        6.86  &     108.5  &        26.46  &        67.0  &         3.92  &         89.5  &     18.62  \\

    106.5  &        12.74  &        127.5  &        2.94  &         73.5  &         6.86  &         84.5  &         4.9  \\

    102.0  &        15.68  &        134.0  &        5.88  &         55.0  &         19.6  &     102.0  &        7.84  \\

     73.35 &              &       90.0 &              &       43.3 &              &       75.3 &              \\

                        SH &            &                       SHALG &            &                        RD &            &                       DIF &            \\

        45.0  &     41.16  &        8.0  &          0.0  &      36.0  &         3.92  &         55.0  &     50.96  \\

        61.0  &     13.72  &        32.5  &     26.46  &        30.0  &         1.96  &         65.5  &     36.26  \\

        46.0  &     33.32  &        61.5  &         14.7  &         36.5  &     65.66  &        67.5  &     32.34  \\

        44.0  &     33.32  &        75.5  &         44.1  &         58.5  &     12.74  &        53.5  &     12.74  \\

        74.0  &         7.84  &     100.5  &        8.82  &         55.0  &         7.84  &         76.0  &     17.64  \\

        82.5  &         8.82  &         88.0  &     27.44  &        76.5  &     49.98  &        86.5  &     40.18  \\

        92.5  &         24.5  &     100.0  &        33.32  &        76.5  &         14.7  &     103.5  &        14.7  \\

        92.0  &         1.96  &     100.0  &        11.76  &        71.0  &         7.84  &     108.0  &        11.76  \\

    119.5  &        4.9  &      118.5  &        8.82  &         75.5  &     10.78  &        101.5  &        0.98  \\

    107.5  &        22.54  &        126.5  &        2.94  &         97.0  &     21.56  &        112.0  &        3.92  \\

      76.4 &              &       81.1 &              &      61.25 &              &       82.9 &              \\

                        DIFALG &            &                           GR &            &                       CUST &            &                         CUST2 &                           \\

        28.0  &         1.96  &         35.0  &     13.72  &        25.0  &     11.76  &        68.0  &     19.6      \\

        61.5  &     22.54  &        54.5  &     26.46  &        53.5  &         6.86  &         42.0  &     15.68     \\

        73.5  &         2.94  &         85.5  &     12.74  &        67.0  &         5.88  &         67.0  &     17.64     \\

        60.0  &     17.64  &        86.0  &         0.0  &      69.0  &         19.6  &         63.0  &     1.96      \\

        57.0  &         7.84  &         92.0  &     23.52  &        78.5  &         14.7  &         85.0  &     29.4      \\

    100.0  &        23.52  &        115.0  &        3.92  &     104.0  &        27.44  &        91.0  &     5.88      \\

        70.5  &     30.38  &        113.5  &        18.62  &        121.0  &        0.0  &      68.0  &     1.96      \\

        86.5  &         14.7  &     126.0  &        9.8  &      121.0  &        25.48  &        96.5  &     20.58     \\

        72.5  &     16.66  &        115.5  &        0.98  &     122.0  &        21.56  &        95.0  &     13.72     \\

        94.5  &         8.82  &     135.0  &        11.76  &        108.5  &        6.86  &     104.0  &    15.68     \\

      70.4 &              &       95.8 &              &      86.95 &              &      77.95 &              \\

\end{tabular}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Arkusz2'
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrr}

        DG &            &                       DGALG &            &                        DJ &            &                           BR &            \\

     79.5  &        30.38  &        98.0  &     21.56  &        38.0  &         1.96  &     121.5  &        4.9  \\

    110.5  &        20.58  &        152.0  &        7.84  &         94.0  &         9.8  &      115.0  &        19.6  \\

    123.0  &        29.4  &     160.5  &        12.74  &        90.0  &     41.16  &        105.0  &        33.32  \\

    141.0  &        39.2  &     162.0  &        7.84  &         99.5  &     18.62  &        171.0  &        19.6  \\

    156.0  &        11.76  &        186.5  &        2.94  &     108.5  &        6.86  &     170.0  &        3.92  \\

    180.5  &        8.82  &     196.0  &        13.72  &        130.0  &        0.0  &      166.0  &        11.76  \\

    179.0  &        21.56  &        192.5  &        2.94  &     136.0  &        21.56  &        161.5  &        24.5  \\

    174.0  &        5.88  &     199.5  &        4.9  &      131.5  &        4.9  &      157.5  &        40.18  \\

    189.0  &        29.4  &     211.5  &        4.9  &      142.0  &        11.76  &        168.5  &        22.54  \\

    187.5  &        2.94  &     211.5  &        16.66  &        121.5  &        16.66  &        173.0  &        11.76  \\

     152.0 &              &      177.0 &              &      109.1 &              &      150.9 &              \\

                        SH &            &                       SHALG &            &                        RD &            &                       DIF &            \\

        82.5  &         8.82  &     107.5  &        6.86  &     105.5  &        24.5  &     109.5  &        22.54  \\

    126.5  &        28.42  &        114.5  &        40.18  &        94.5  &     81.34  &        131.5  &        0.98  \\

    118.5  &        30.38  &        163.5  &        4.9  &      108.0  &        5.88  &     141.0  &        3.92  \\

    124.5  &        26.46  &        185.0  &        19.6  &     131.5  &        14.7  &     155.0  &        3.92  \\

    143.0  &        1.96  &     188.5  &        0.98  &     146.5  &        22.54  &        164.0  &        3.92  \\

    162.0  &        3.92  &     193.0  &        7.84  &     174.5  &        6.86  &     173.5  &        38.22  \\

    177.0  &        3.92  &     187.0  &        29.4  &     157.5  &        20.58  &        196.5  &        28.42  \\

    176.5  &        18.62  &        195.5  &        18.62  &        193.5  &        0.98  &     196.0  &        3.92  \\

    204.0  &        7.84  &     208.0  &        1.96  &     170.0  &        23.52  &        194.5  &        0.98  \\

    186.0  &        23.52  &        200.5  &        8.82  &     176.0  &        3.92  &     210.5  &        0.98  \\

    150.05 &              &      174.3 &              &     145.75 &              &      167.2 &              \\

                        DIFALG &            &                           GR &            &                       CUST &            &                         CUST2 &                           \\

    119.5  &        14.7  &     108.0  &        41.16  &        106.5  &        24.5  &     125.5  &    12.74     \\

    142.0  &        23.52  &        150.0  &        3.92  &     105.0  &        0.0  &      128.0  &    23.52     \\

    158.0  &        49.0  &     197.0  &        5.88  &     141.0  &        1.96  &     168.5  &        0.98      \\

    173.0  &        29.4  &     172.5  &        16.66  &        171.5  &        30.38  &        174.5  &    40.18     \\

    180.5  &        0.98  &     180.5  &        6.86  &     194.5  &        4.9  &      188.5  &    18.62     \\

    178.5  &        28.42  &        203.5  &        20.58  &        195.5  &        0.98  &     202.5  &    10.78     \\

    202.5  &        14.7  &     197.5  &        24.5  &     208.0  &        11.76  &        205.5  &    20.58     \\

    185.5  &        0.98  &     212.5  &        8.82  &     205.5  &        8.82  &     204.5  &        0.98      \\

    194.0  &        3.92  &     217.5  &        12.74  &        194.0  &        17.64  &        202.5  &        2.94      \\

    175.0  &        31.36  &        209.0  &        15.68  &        202.5  &        0.98  &     201.0  &    13.72     \\

    170.85 &              &      184.8 &              &      172.4 &              &      180.1 &              \\

\end{tabular}  

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Arkusz2'
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrr}

        DG &            &                       DGALG &            &                        DJ &            &                           BR &            \\

    115.0  &        1.96  &     137.5  &        10.78  &        115.5  &        14.7  &     169.5  &        16.66  \\

    176.5  &        20.58  &        204.5  &        0.98  &     121.5  &        12.74  &        173.5  &        0.98  \\

    187.0  &        27.44  &        209.0  &        19.6  &     134.0  &        15.68  &        179.0  &        19.6  \\

    182.0  &        35.28  &        223.0  &        25.48  &        157.0  &        37.24  &        223.5  &        20.58  \\

    202.0  &        19.6  &     233.0  &        9.8  &      152.0  &        1.96  &     212.0  &        23.52  \\

    238.5  &        6.86  &     235.5  &        12.74  &        168.0  &        19.6  &     210.5  &        18.62  \\

    229.0  &        13.72  &        240.5  &        0.98  &     183.5  &        6.86  &     217.5  &        12.74  \\

    227.5  &        0.98  &     234.0  &        7.84  &     169.0  &        23.52  &        219.5  &        20.58  \\

    224.0  &        3.92  &     239.5  &        2.94  &     190.5  &        12.74  &        207.0  &        17.64  \\

    228.5  &        16.66  &        245.5  &        2.94  &     190.0  &        27.44  &        218.5  &        16.66  \\

     201.0 &              &      220.2 &              &      158.1 &              &     203.05 &              \\

                        SH &            &                       SHALG &            &                        RD &            &                       DIF &            \\

    144.5  &        38.22  &        133.5  &        42.14  &        182.5  &        4.9  &      167.0  &        52.92  \\

    179.5  &        30.38  &        171.0  &        21.56  &        165.0  &        15.68  &        180.0  &        13.72  \\

    204.5  &        14.7  &     220.5  &        10.78  &        168.5  &        59.78  &        197.5  &        2.94  \\

    201.5  &        18.62  &        226.0  &        5.88  &     192.0  &        15.68  &        216.0  &        11.76  \\

    215.0  &        19.6  &     233.5  &        6.86  &     200.5  &        6.86  &     221.5  &        6.86  \\

    203.0  &        0.0  &      229.0  &        0.0  &      205.5  &        26.46  &        233.0  &        5.88  \\

    207.0  &        27.44  &        230.5  &        14.7  &     212.0  &        3.92  &     234.0  &        3.92  \\

    221.0  &        3.92  &     235.5  &        8.82  &     218.0  &        17.64  &        238.5  &        6.86  \\

    235.5  &        24.5  &     243.0  &        0.0  &      222.5  &        2.94  &     239.5  &        2.94  \\

    237.0  &        9.8  &      243.0  &        3.92  &     230.5  &        6.86  &     241.0  &        3.92  \\

    204.85 &              &     216.55 &              &      199.7 &              &      216.8 &              \\

                        DIFALG &            &                           GR &            &                       CUST &            &                         CUST2 &                           \\

    173.0  &        0.0  &      178.5  &        24.5  &     185.0  &        0.0  &      163.5  &        53.9      \\

    219.0  &        19.6  &     216.5  &        12.74  &        196.0  &        9.8  &      208.5  &    16.66     \\

    200.0  &        3.92  &     225.0  &        5.88  &     200.0  &        25.48  &        221.0  &        0.0   \\

    229.5  &        6.86  &     237.0  &        3.92  &     220.5  &        2.94  &     232.5  &        2.94      \\

    227.0  &        25.48  &        235.0  &        9.8  &      223.0  &        21.56  &        238.5  &    10.78     \\

    235.5  &        4.9  &      235.0  &        9.8  &      244.5  &        2.94  &     226.0  &        1.96      \\

    242.5  &        8.82  &     236.0  &        0.0  &      235.5  &        2.94  &     241.0  &        9.8   \\

    232.0  &        0.0  &      246.0  &        0.0  &      240.5  &        16.66  &        245.5  &        0.98      \\

    232.0  &        11.76  &        246.0  &        5.88  &     242.5  &        4.9  &      240.5  &        6.86      \\

    229.5  &        10.78  &        241.5  &        0.98  &     237.5  &        18.62  &        242.0  &    13.72     \\

     222.0 &              &     229.65 &              &      222.5 &              &      225.9 &              \\

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Arkusz2'
\begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrr}

        DG &            &                       DGALG &            &                        DJ &            &                           BR &            \\

    201.0  &        5.88  &     173.0  &        33.32  &        164.0  &        5.88  &     196.5  &        49.98  \\

    226.0  &        0.0  &      232.5  &        18.62  &        175.0  &        0.0  &      215.5  &        18.62  \\

    223.0  &        17.64  &        244.5  &        4.9  &      180.0  &        11.76  &        208.0  &        1.96  \\

    234.0  &        1.96  &     251.0  &        0.0  &      183.5  &        2.94  &     248.0  &        5.88  \\

    240.5  &        2.94  &     254.0  &        5.88  &     172.0  &        1.96  &     245.5  &        4.9  \\

    252.5  &        4.9  &      256.5  &        0.98  &     204.5  &        8.82  &     247.5  &        2.94  \\

    253.0  &        1.96  &     258.5  &        4.9  &      222.0  &        11.76  &        243.0  &        9.8  \\

    250.0  &        7.84  &     259.0  &        0.0  &      223.0  &        23.52  &        246.0  &        5.88  \\

    248.5  &        2.94  &     259.5  &        2.94  &     215.5  &        0.98  &     249.0  &        3.92  \\

    252.5  &        4.9  &      260.0  &        5.88  &     229.5  &        0.98  &     250.0  &        0.0  \\

     238.1 &              &     244.85 &              &      196.9 &              &      234.9 &              \\

                        SH &            &                       SHALG &            &                        RD &            &                       DIF &            \\

    200.0  &        9.8  &      194.0  &        5.88  &     212.0  &        23.52  &        212.5  &        0.98  \\

    214.0  &        19.6  &     216.0  &        13.72  &        216.0  &        25.48  &        226.5  &        8.82  \\

    229.0  &        3.92  &     243.5  &        6.86  &     227.5  &        10.78  &        243.5  &        6.86  \\

    228.5  &        0.98  &     245.5  &        4.9  &      223.0  &        5.88  &     246.5  &        4.9  \\

    242.0  &        9.8  &      251.5  &        4.9  &      236.5  &        0.98  &     247.5  &        2.94  \\

    237.5  &        0.98  &     255.0  &        0.0  &      237.5  &        10.78  &        248.5  &        4.9  \\

    247.0  &        9.8  &      252.0  &        5.88  &     243.5  &        6.86  &     258.0  &        5.88  \\

    252.0  &        9.8  &      253.0  &        3.92  &     244.0  &        5.88  &     255.5  &        2.94  \\

    254.5  &        2.94  &     257.0  &        3.92  &     242.5  &        4.9  &      255.5  &        0.98  \\

    260.0  &        1.96  &     259.0  &        1.96  &     244.5  &        6.86  &     257.0  &        3.92  \\

    236.45 &              &     242.65 &              &      232.7 &              &      245.1 &              \\

                        DIFALG &            &                           GR &            &                       CUST &            &                         CUST2 &                           \\

    212.5  &        4.9  &      229.0  &        5.88  &     213.0  &        9.8  &      226.0  &        5.88      \\

    244.0  &        5.88  &     237.5  &        2.94  &     212.0  &        23.52  &        245.5  &        14.7      \\

    239.5  &        0.98  &     243.5  &        2.94  &     223.5  &        8.82  &     252.0  &        5.88      \\

    249.0  &        1.96  &     250.0  &        1.96  &     240.5  &        4.9  &      257.5  &        0.98      \\

    250.0  &        0.0  &      249.5  &        4.9  &      253.5  &        4.9  &      255.5  &        0.98      \\

    256.0  &        1.96  &     251.0  &        1.96  &     256.5  &        8.82  &     260.5  &        6.86      \\

    250.5  &        2.94  &     254.0  &        1.96  &     257.5  &        4.9  &      255.0  &        3.92      \\

    255.5  &        2.94  &     255.5  &        4.9  &      257.0  &        3.92  &     257.5  &        2.94      \\

    257.0  &        0.0  &      257.5  &        2.94  &     256.5  &        0.98  &     256.5  &        0.98      \\

    254.0  &        0.0  &      260.0  &        3.92  &     259.0  &        1.96  &     261.5  &        8.82      \\

     246.8 &              &     248.75 &              &      242.9 &              &     252.75 &              \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your third table is missing `\end{tabular}` and also remove the empty lines.

Comment: The compilation error you should be getting, viz., " LaTeX Error: \begin{tabular} on input line <xxx> ended by \end{document}", should be a tip-off that you're missing an `\end{tabular}` statement somewhere. A separate matter: even though it's not doing any harm in the case at hand, I'd also get rid of the mysterious `•` symbol in the document class declaration.

Comment: Syntax error, solved and explained in comments.